# How To Get Array Sum

Tags: php, arrays, sum, filtering

I have 2 arrays.

```
$fruits = [
    'mango' => 20,
    'apple' => 30,
    'orange' => 10,
    'banana' => 5,
];

$purchased = ['mango','banana'];
```

How do I get the sum of the values on the `$fruits` array that are only available on the `$purchased` array? That is get the sum = 25

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 4):

Try a loop -

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($purchased as $v) {
   $sum += (!empty($fruits[$v]) ? $fruits[$v] : 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Filter the `$fruits` array to keep only the purchased keys.
2. Sum all values that remain.

Here is a function-based approach that flips the `$purchased` element's keys and values, then filters `$fruits`, then sums the remaining values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rABLp))

```
$fruits = [
    'mango' => 20,
    'apple' => 30,
    'orange' => 10,
    'banana' => 5,
];

$purchased = ['mango','banana'];
echo array_sum(array_intersect_key($fruits,array_flip($purchased))),"\n";

$purchased = ['mango','banana','orange','apple'];
echo array_sum(array_intersect_key($fruits,array_flip($purchased))),"\n";

$purchased = [];
echo array_sum(array_intersect_key($fruits,array_flip($purchased)));
```

Output:

```
25
65
0
```

*Note, this won't be as fast as a loop, but it does allow a single-line operation and doesn't need to declare a *tally* variable.